# admin_logout issue in cakephp

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I have enabled admin_actions in my cakePHP project. I have a **logout()** for normal employees and **admin_logout()** for admin logout. Both actions belong to EmployeesController.

The code inside both logout actions is the same,except for the flash message.

**admin_logout():**

```
$this->Session->destroy();
$this->Session->setFlash('You have been logged out of admin dashboard!','flash_success');
$this->redirect('/employees/login');
```

**logout()**

```
$this->Session->destroy();
$this->Session->setFlash('You have been logged out!','flash_success');
$this->redirect('/employees/login');
```

The **logout** is working perfectly and destroys the session. But not the **admin_logout()**.

For debugging, i tried this in **admin_logout()**:

```
$this->Session->delete('Admin');
$this->Session->setFlash('You have been logged out of admin dashboard!','flash_success');
$this->redirect('/employees/login');
```

It is also working. But it still wont destroy the complete session variable. I could fix this by using normal **logout()** for both admin and employee. But out of curiosity, whats going wrong here?

EDIT: Needed behavior is the destruction of session variable, then redirection with flash message. But what happens is redirection and flash message is getting displayed BUT session var is not getting destroyed!

Comment: What does the admin_logout action do ? instead of loggin out

Comment: It does nothing else. Simply destroy the session and display message.

Comment: I meant the erronomous behaviour not the needed behavior

Comment: The error is that the session is not getting destroyed by the admin_logout(). I can still access the admin values.

Comment: It displays the flash message and perform redirection. But its not destroying the session variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a fix for your problem, but a slightly more elegant approach to the logout process:
Create only one logout method in your class, one without prefix. Like:

```
public function logout(){
}
```

Now, in all your views create a logout link explicitly nullifying the `admin` prefix:

```
echo $this->Html->link('logout',
    array('admin'=>false,'controller'=>'employees','action'=>'logout')
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Your method is working. But is there no fix for this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a fix for this issue. But to be honest: this is exactly the reason why you would use CakePHP and its features like the Auth Component. So you don't have to spend hours on ghost-bugs like these.

Comment: Hmm.. :) I wanted to use Auth component. But found it bit difficult to grasp and ended up with this!

Comment: I completely understand :) I had the same thing. Still: take 3 hours, and dive into it. It will pay off in the end. (and DO use CakePHP 2.x because the Auth Component has become a bit more transparent compared to 1.3)

Answer (score 0):

If you use 2.0 you should do

```
 $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
```

or

```
$this->Auth->logout();
```

for your redirects

Comment: Isn't this possible only if im using Auth component? Correct me if im wrong!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have separate flash messages for admins, you could simply use an if statement in the logout method to check whatever variable determines if the user is an admin.

```
    if($this->Auth->user('is_admin')){
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('You have been logged out of admin dashboard!','flash_success'));
    }
    else{
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('You have been logged out!','flash_success'));
```

I may be missing something here but doesn't

```
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
```

destroy the session?